# Using IIS7 can I get the IP that accessed a webpage at a certain time?

Tags: iis, logging, ip-address

Using IIS7 can I get the IP that accessed a webpage at a certain time?

Such as 3:41:17 am? Not a programming question, but I need to track down whoever connected and trashed my web project. So please dont close this question.

Comment: IP addresses can be spoofed.

Comment: Well whoever did this, connected via web, ftp and ms sql. I think I found him but I'd love someone with more knowledge to look at the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to enable IIS logging.  This is done at the web pool level and usually creates an extensive .txt file with data like Time, Response Size, URI requested, etc.  As Dennis said IPs *can* be spoofed, and anonymous proxies used...